# React infinite scroll in a container with dynamic height?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm using **react-infinite** from (https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite), to have data loading when user scrolls.

This is a mobile app, and the container height is dynamic (aprox.: 60vh), each item have an height of 46px.

I need to pass the **containerHeight** and the **elementHeight** to the element. How can I get them?

I wan't to avoid the use of JQuery, i.e.:

```
var height = $(this.refs.transactionsDiv.getDOMNode()).
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like :

```
React.findDOMNode(my_node).offsetHeight;
```

for you containerHeight and directly pass your item height since you already know it.

On a side note I've had issues with react-infinite which do not yet support variable height (see https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite/issues/62). If you want something more flexible, try react-list (https://github.com/orgsync/react-list) which do not require container or element height and remove dom nodes when not visible.

Comment: If we use react-list, could you advise a way to render a loading spinner as in react-infinite?